# Image on Angular project, preload doesn't work

Tags: angular, preload, image-preloader

In my Angular Project I am trying to improve the Lighthouse performance score.

Apparently, an image affect negatively the performance score. In the Lighthouse console I see the following suggestion:

```
Preload Largest Contentful Paint image
0.45s
If the LCP element is dynamically added to the page, you should preload the image in order to improve LCP. Learn more about preloading LCP elements.LCP
```

So, by following some discussion, I tried to add this line in the header of the index.html file:

```
<link rel="preconnect" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="https://example.com/test/img1.webp" type="image/webp" />
```

But the performance didn't change and the performance are still low. What is wrong, in my image preload strategy?

Comment: Any difference if using `preload` instead of `preconnect`?

Comment: No difference, the problem is not there... Any other idea? Thanks

Comment: How about `prefetch`? From the docs "prefetch specifies that the browser should preemptively fetch and cache the target resource as it is likely to be required for a follow-up navigation". If that's not it I'd suggest you try to use dev tools, specifically Chrome Network tab, to get a firm understanding of the load times for each of the apps resources.

Comment: Nothing changed, thanks